# Lodash - "FAQS" should display as "FAQs"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, lodash

I am using `lodash` - A JavaScript utility library - with my AngularJS code.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
  <label>{{question  | startCase}}</label>
</div>
```

This is the documentation for startCase
https://lodash.com/docs#startCase

I have many questions - approximately 1000. If a question has the word `FAQS` it should display as `FAQs`. How can I do this?

Comment: Make a filter that does exactly that - replace `FAQS` with `FAQs`. You could make a generic one that has a list of mappings instead of just one. Also, the `startCase` algorithm does not know English, it cannot know it has to do this for you automatically.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by making filter like this:

```
app.filter('fixFAQ', function () {
  return function (input) {
      return input.replace('FAQS', 'FAQs');
  };
});
```

And then use it after startCase: `{{question | startCase | fixFAQ}}`